# Only extract a few properties from form

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to only get some properties from a form on submit?

```
<html><body>
<FORM name="foo" id="foo" onSubmit="dosubmit();return false;">
    <INPUT type="text" name="s" id="s"><BR/>
    <INPUT type="text" name="s2" id="s2"><BR/>

    <select name="si" id="si">
    <option>SomeOption_1</option>
    <option>SomeOption_2</option>
    <option>SomeOption_3</option>
    </select><BR/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="postDataSubmit">
</FORM>

<script>
function dosubmit() 
{
    //Extract value of S2 and the chosen option (si) from the form here, and nothing else. Show them in an alert.
}
</script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: You need to switch the positions for the closing tag for html and body at the end.

Comment: @LarryBattle lol nice catch. I added those for clarification while making my question, wasn't really paying attention. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function dosubmit()
{
    alert(document.getElementById('s2').value);
    alert(document.getElementById('si').options[document.getElementById('si').selectedIndex].value);
}
```

And by the way, if this is all you're trying to do, then you don't need a form. You can do this with any regular button:

```
<button onclick="dosubmit()">Show values</button>
```

Comment: Lol @ downvote. [Not enough jQuery](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif), I guess?

Comment: @natli: Couldn't agree more. Did you look at the link in my comment? I find it hilarious.

Answer (score 3):

using pure javascript(as using JQuery is IMHO not necessary for this simple task) you can
simply write:

```
alert(document.forms.foo.s2.value);
alert(document.forms.foo.si.value);
```

Because you have used name for each for your inputs you can access all elements on your form through document.forms;